# I don't see any errors in my Angular code, but when I use the developer tools, the username doesn't appear due to text interpolation errors

Tags: angular

I don't see any errors in my Angular code, but when I use the developer tools, the username doesn't appear due to text interpolation errors.you know the answer?

authservice.ts

```
 public get useraccountValue(): Useraccount{
return this.useraccountSubject.value; }
```

Useraccount.ts

```
export class Useraccount{

id:string ='';
username: string='';
name:string='';
password:string='';
email:string=''; }
```

header.ts

```
user= this.authservice.useraccountValue;
 constructor(private authservice:AuthService) {
    //this.user
this.authservice.user.subscribe(x => this.user = x);
console.log(this.user);}
```

header.html

```
<ul class="info_ul">
    <li>{{user.username}}</li>
    <li><a (click)="logout($event)">logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

UseraccountSubject assigned to authservice and BhaviorSubject Service

```
export class AuthService {
 
  private useraccountSubject: BehaviorSubject<Useraccount>;
  public user: Observable<Useraccount>;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router:Router){
    this.useraccountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Useraccount>(null as any);
    this.user = this.useraccountSubject.asObservable();

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("USER")){ 
      const user =sessionStorage.getItem("USER");
      if(user){
        this.useraccountSubject.next(JSON.parse(user));
      }
    }
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (err.status === 200) {
      console.error('Error:',err.error.data)
    } else {
      console.error(`Backend error ${err.status}`)
    }
    return throwError('Try again')
  }
  private handleErrorsingup(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (err.status === 201) {
      console.error('Error:',err.error.data)
    } else {
      alert('faild');
      console.error(`Backend error ${err.status}`)
    }
    return throwError('Try again.')
  }


  login(username:string,password:string){ 

    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/signin/`, params, {observe:'response', withCredentials: true})//withCredentials:true
    .pipe(map(user=>{
      catchError(this.handleError)
      sessionStorage.setItem("USER", JSON.stringify(user));
      return user;

    }))

  }
  signup(email:string,password:string,name:string ){
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append('email', email);
    params.append('password', password);
    params.append('name', name);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/signup/`, params, {observe:'response', withCredentials: true})
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleErrorsingup)
    )
  }
  logout(){
    return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/signout/`, {}).subscribe(
      response=>{

        this.useraccountSubject.next(null as any)
        sessionStorage.clear(); 
        this.router.navigate(['login'])
      }
    )

  }
  isloggedIn(){

  }

  public get useraccountValue(): Useraccount{
    return this.useraccountSubject.value;
  }
}
```

Error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null(reading 'username')

Comment: aren't you missing parenthesis on `user = this.authservice.useraccountValue()`?

Comment: yes 
If () is used, it is a get accessor and cannot be called. an error appear

Comment: Have you actually got a 'text interpolation error'? What is it exactly?

Comment: hello - devtools ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null(reading 'username') it is showing like this

Comment: Can you attach the code for `AuthService`? Look like `useraccountSubject` is a `Subject` /  `BehaviorSubject`. Can you show how you assign the value to `useraccountSubject`?

Comment: of course i added what you said

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular.
You are trying to access a `user` value while is is null, without ensuring that the user exists.

This is the most common error in the large part of the most common languages.

Given you initialize your subject like so:

```
this.useraccountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Useraccount>(null as any);
```

When a null creeps into your code you have to handle it.
You have a lot of alternatives, but I', just listing two, for the sake of exposition:

```html
<!-- 1. do not render the block it the user is null -->
<ul *ngIf="user" class="info_ul">
    <li>{{user.username}}</li>
    <li><a (click)="logout($event)">logout</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- 2. Make the expression null safe. I don't think it's the best for the case,
        but I'm demonstrating it anyway. -->
<ul class="info_ul">
    <li>{{ user != null ? user.username : '-' }}</li>
    <li><a (click)="logout($event)">logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I suspect that if user is null, you should not have a "logout" element anyway.

Comment: A. Chiesa, neither method worked

Comment: "neither method worked" is useless. You have an error. It's the same as before? Has it changed? I'm pretty confident your error means you have `user.x` somewhere in your code and you try to execute it when user is null.

Comment: When I use the method suggested by devloptools I don't get the changed error but it doesn't show up on the screen

Comment: Do you have any errors on the browser console on Browser's dev tools?

Comment: In the first method ngif, only null is displayed in console and no logout username.
In the second method there are no errors in the console, but the username still doesn't appear.